# How to access picture resources loaded by the CSS engine?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I am using CSS to style a javafx application. The stylesheet refers to picture resources throught url(...) directive and everythings works great.
Now, I am using the exact same images in a non-javafx component (mapsforge). Currently, those resources are loaded a second time to be made accessible from the mapsforge drawing context.

It does work ok, but the duplication and cpu/memory waste smell quite bad.

Thus, I am wondering wether there is a way to access the resources loaded through the CSS engine from the outside. I have been searching for a while for such accessors without success. Are those resources handled in native code (Prism) and uploaded in gpu memory directly ? Any chance to somehow get an InputStream ?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that is possible. Create an Image and pass it around to your different ImageViews.